# How to target an event by contained string?

Tags: windows, powershell, scheduled-tasks

In powershell script i have line:

```
$LogOnEvents = Get-EventLog -Logname security -Message '*name*адрес:*.*.*.*' -Newest 1
```

This line every time picking wrong one for me. Problem with event triggering.
 **Can i use *filter* in task scheluder with same string instead of condition in script?**
This filter will allow me to pick needed event.
 Now i have 1000's events with certain ID. And they not synchronized with user logon.
 Some event appear between user logon and actual note about logon.
 Maybe its wrong explantaion, but still i need check for string in filter of schelude.
Will thankfull for all!

Answer (score 0):

Leave you code in your script.
You can use RegEx to match the string your are after to select the record line you want.

```
[regex]::matches($strText, $pattern)
```